# Apache redirection http to https

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

i try to activate redirection for a website, http to https.

Content of an **.htacces** founded

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /centreon/index.html
```

When i add this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

After an httpd reload or restart, the redirection http to https is not working. Maybe a rule conflict ?
I am sorry but i am very newb about this kind of rules.

About the global configuration, i got this into
**10-centreon.conf** ->
`RedirectMatch ^/$ /centreon`

The main site is not an virtualhost

the **ssl.conf** got `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`

Many thanks for any help

Comment: It's not clear what `10-centreon.conf` is supposed to do and where it is defined and included.
If this is a (symlinked) configuration in `conf-enabled` or `sites-enabled` and loaded before your redirection block, then this would redirect the main site to your 404 page `/centreon/index.html`. What happens if you comment that line and reload Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this short answer, this should be a comment, but i cant comment yet.

You could try to redirect all that goes into the http virtual host and because the port 80 and port 443 are handled by two different virtual hosts the rules only apply to http traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, finaly i got it with that into *10-centron.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName supervision
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```